# Last entry on join table

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I've two table "questionnaires" and "question" link by  the table "question_questionnaire". I want to retrive all questions of the last questionnaire with questionnaire.cible="personnel". I'm using laravel 5.3.

I've tried this but it doesn't work :

```
DB::table('questions')
 ->join('question_questionnaire','question_questionnaire.question_id','=','questions.id')
 ->join('questionnaires','questionnaires.id','=','question_questionnaire.questionnaire_id')
 ->orderBy('questionnaires.created_at','desc')
 ->first()->where('questionnaires.cible','=','personnel')->get();
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Are you getting any result? You need to remove `first()` for a start. That will get you only the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DB::table('questions')
        ->join('question_questionnaire','question_questionnaire.question_id','=','questions.id')
        ->join('questionnaires','questionnaires.id','=','question_questionnaire.questionnaire_id')
        ->whereRaw('questionnaires.id = (select max(id) from questionnaires where cible = ?)',['personel'])
        ->get();
```